# Adding li element with Javascript and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just start to use JQuery and I want to add li element in my HTML when I click on a button.

My Html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="filtres">
      <input id="filtre1" type="button" value="filtre 1" onclick="test()">
    </div>
    <div id="liste">
      <ul>
        <li>Bonjour</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And my js file :

```
function test() {
    console.log("On clique");
    $("<li>Coucou</li>").appendTo("<ul>");
}
```

Unfortunately, It doesn't work and I don't understand why.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Try to import jquery before, and then your own file

Comment: No it doesn't change anything. The console.log() display "On clique" in the firefox console.

Comment: You're appending to a new `ul`, not the existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because your selector is incorrect. `appendTo('<ul>')` is trying to *create* a new `ul` element in memory and append the `li` to that. You instead need to use `appendTo('ul')`, without the angle brackets.

I'd also suggest you use unobtrusive event handlers instead of the outdated `onclick` attributes. Here's the full example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="filtres">
      <input id="filtre1" type="button" value="filtre 1" />
    </div>
    <div id="liste">
      <ul>
        <li>Bonjour</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('#filtre1').on('click', function() {
    console.log("On clique");
    $("<li>Coucou</li>").appendTo("ul");
  });
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
function test() {
  $('ul').append('<li>Hello!</li>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="liste">
      <ul>
        <li>Bonjour</li>
      </ul>
</div>
<button onclick="test()">append</button>
```

append() will add an element at the end

Answer (score 0):

```js
function test() {
  $('#liste > ul').append('<li>Coucou</li>');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="filtres">
  <input id="filtre1" type="button" value="filtre 1" onclick="test()">
</div>

<div id="liste">
  <ul>
    <li>Bonjour</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="filtres">
      <input id="filtre1" type="button" value="filtre 1" />
    </div>
    <div id="liste">
      <ul>
        <li>Bonjour</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```